# How to Retrieve and Store JSON data into Database using Laravel

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 in my application, and I have this JSON record I have in Controller:

```
public function findLeaveCount(Request $request)
{
    $nationalholidays = HrHolidayDate::select('holiday_date')
        ->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($nationalholiday) {
            return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $nationalholiday->holiday_date)
                ->format('Y-m-d');
        });       
    return response()->json([
        'nationalholidays' => $nationalholidays,
    ]);           
}
```

I retrieved it this way:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var holidayDays = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '{{ route('
      get.employeeleavecounts.all ') }}',
      data: {
        'id': air_id
      },
      dataType: 'json', //return data will be json
      success: function(data) {
        $('#nationalholidays').val(data.nationalholidays);
        holidayDays = data.nationalholidays;
        console.log(holidayDays);
      },
      error: function() {

      }
    });
  });
}); <
/script>
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="nationalholidays" class="form-control">
```

Which Gives me this in the console:

```
(7) ["2020-11-12", "2020-11-16", "2020-11-19", "2020-11-30", "2020-12-14", "2020-12-01", "2020-12-10"]
0: "2020-11-12"
1: "2020-11-16"
2: "2020-11-19"
3: "2020-11-30"
4: "2020-12-14"
5: "2020-12-01"
6: "2020-12-10"
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Then:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="nationalholidays" class="form-control">
```

is presented this way:

```
2020-11-12,2020-11-16,2020-11-19,2020-11-30,2020-12-14,2020-12-01,2020-12-10
```

How do I make :

```
<input type="hidden" id="nationalholidays" class="form-control">
```

Present the data this way:

```
 ["2020-11-12", "2020-11-16", "2020-11-19", "2020-11-30", "2020-12-14", "2020-12-01", "2020-12-10"]
```

because that's the format I want to store it into the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned data is in JSON, and since you set the type of your request to JSON, it's immediately parsed and turned into a JavaScript array.

You want to display it as a JSON string, so simply turn the array into JSON again:

```js
$('#nationalholidays').val(JSON.stringify(data.nationalholidays))
```